# How to find string in output of subprocess.Popen.communicate

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to find a string in the output of proc.communicate for subprocess.Popen.
My code looks like this:

```py
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["./runCommand.sh" +  " -i " + ip + " -c " + cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = proc.communicate()
    p_status = proc.wait()
    if 'someword' in output:
        #dosomething
```

It seems that I can't find the word I'm looking for in the output.
The output looks like this when printed:

`(b'blabla someword\blabla\n', None)`

Do I need to convert this in order to find something with "in"?

---

Edit:
Thanks so far for your answers!
I changed it to "output[0], but still I get an error
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`
What can I do here? Use decode()?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a two elements tuple, you can use `in` if you access to the first element of the tuple:

```
>>> 'someword' in (b'blabla someword\blabla\n', None)[0]
True
```

So you need to replace `output` with `output[0]` to make your code work.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting both stdout + stderr into `output`, so you need to check `if 'someword' in output[0]`:

Or better yet:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["./runCommand.sh" +  " -i " + ip + " -c " + cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, _ = proc.communicate() # or output, err = proc.communicate()
p_status = proc.wait()
if 'someword' in output:
    #dosomething
```

---

*always be checking the doc*:

```
In [7]: subprocess.Popen.communicate?
Signature: subprocess.Popen.communicate(self, input=None)
Docstring:
Interact with process: Send data to stdin.  Read data from
stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.  Wait for
process to terminate.  The optional input argument should be a
string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data
should be sent to the child.

communicate() returns a tuple (stdout, stderr).  <<<---
File:      /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py
Type:      instancemethod
```